# Checking last line of log file before moving on or repeating command

Tags: powershell

I'm struggling a little bit with this logic, and I'm hoping someone can point out and explain where I'm going wrong - I've tried all sorts of variations but haven't been able to get it quite right.

What I want is for it to run the uninstall.bat script and monitor the log file for the exit code. Then if the exit code was 0 continue with the script, if the exit code was anything other than 0 repeat the uninstall.bat up to a maximum of 4 times.

When I try to wildcard either side of the string with * it doesn't work - I don't think it's the string that's the issue though, I think it's the method/approach I'm taking.

Another slight complication is that the log file will always have 'CcmSetup is exiting with return code' as part of the last line initially, this changes as the bat file runs, but when completed will end with 'CcmSetup is exiting with return code 0' in the log file.

```
do{
    $count = 1
    Write-Output "Uninstalling Software Center - attempt $count"
    Start Uninstall-Local.bat
    $count++
    While((Get-Content C:\Windows\ccmsetup\Logs\ccmsetup.log -tail 1 -Wait | Select-String -pattern "CcmSetup is exiting with return code" -SimpleMatch -Quiet)){Start-sleep -s 10}
    } until((Get-Content C:\Windows\ccmsetup\Logs\ccmsetup.log -tail 1 -Wait | Select-String -pattern "CcmSetup is exiting with return code 0" -SimpleMatch -Quiet) -or $count -gt 3)
```

On the while() I've tried it with -notmatch and -not 
seperately. It doesn't seem to evaluate to false and thus doesn't move on from there.

Thank you in advance, any help/insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize your $count Variable before you enter the loop! Currently you are resetting it with every loop back to 1.

Personally I would use the -Wait Parameter of Start-Process instead of looping through a log file waiting for a specific string. Something like

```
$count = 1
$LogFilePath = 'C:\Windows\ccmsetup\Logs\ccmsetup.log'
do {
    Start-Process Uninstall-Local.bat -Wait
    $count++
} until ((Get-Content $LogFilePath -tail 1 | Select-String -pattern "CcmSetup is exiting with return code 0" -SimpleMatch) -or ($count -gt 3))
```

Comment: I can't believe the $count was inside the loop. Good catch though!

Comment: My only worry about using the Start-Process -wait approach like you have suggested is that the .bat file kicks off the installer with the required parameters. But the CCM install runs in yet another process. 

So the .bat will finish way before the actual install finishes (which is why I need to monitor the log file for that line).

Comment: After some testing it seems that you need to add conditional check to the while loop.`while ((Get-Content -Path $LogFilePath -Tail 1 | Select-String -Pattern "CcmSetup is exiting with return code" -SimpleMatch) -eq $null)
    {
        Start-Sleep 10
    }`

Comment: That's amazing, I would never have figured that out - It makes sense though.

Can't thank you enough :)